# Buffered Readers and Writers

Tags: java

So I have an issue, I read in a textbook, that the buffer only writes to the text file when its full and only reads from the text file when its empty
So assuming I want to write just one String "James", surely that wouldn't make the buffer full, so why does it still get written to a file testout.txt

```java
package com.javatpoint;  

import java.io.*;

public class BufferedWriterExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {     
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:\\testout.txt");  
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(writer);  
        buffer.write("Welcome to javaTpoint.");  enter code here
        buffer.close();  
        System.out.println("Sucenter code herecess");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're closing it.

Comment: @Mena, does that also apply to readers, what if I want to read from a text file and the buffer size, cannot accommodate the text

Comment: If you close either, you can't reuse them. The `BufferedReader` class also features a handy `readLine` method so you don't have to  bother much about buffer sizes but just read until the next line break. Or of course, you can specify your own buffer.

Comment: @Mena  What i'm saying is, lets say you have a very large text file and your buffer can only contain half of it, the readLine() method reads each line till,there's nothing left in the buffer, and at that point you've already closed the buffer, what happens to the remaining text in the file?

Comment: Nothing. It stays there.

Answer (score 3):

> I read in a textbook, that the buffer [in a `BufferedWriter`] only writes to the text file when it is full ...

That is incorrect<sup>1</sup>.  In fact, a `BufferedWriter` will write to the `Writer` that it wraps:

- when a call to one of the write methods fills the buffer<sup>2</sup>, *OR*
- when you call `bw.flush()`, *OR*
- when you call `bw.close()`.

These will typically write data to the file.  (But not always.  It depends on the behavior of the wrapped `Writer`.)

So the reason that all of the data is written in your example is that you are calling `buffer.close()`.

---

> ... and [a `BufferedReader`] only reads from the text file when its empty.

This is correct, but not relevant to the rest of your question.

---

<sup>1 - You probably misread the text book.</sup>

<sup>2 - Actually it is a bit more complicated than this because a `write(char[], ...)` call that writes a large enough number of characters will first flush the buffer, and then write directly from the `char[]` to the wrapped stream.  It bypasses the buffer to avoid an unnecessary copy.</sup>